# Composition vs Inheritance and GUI toolkits

Tags: user-interface, inheritance

It's said that composition is preferred over inheritance.  Every single open source GUI toolkit however uses inheritance for the drawn widgets (windows, labels, frames, buttons, etc).  I checked Qt, wxWidgets, and GTK+.  Is there an example of a GUI toolkit (written in any language) that uses composition instead of inheritance to separate the various widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem that you're facing with those GUI Toolkits ?

I think, They derive from a common Widget base class so that they all expose a minimum interface. So you could write code that can work with any SpecializedWidgetType. I think this is a good use of inheritance..

[Prefer composition to inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002).. but do not shoehorn composition where inheritance is the right answer. There are always exceptions to a rule/guideline.

Comment: No problem.  I was just curious if there was an example.  I suppose there isn't and your answer makes sense.